# Pandas filtering all rows where is a keyword could be in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

ev is a dataframe that contains all the shots from the 20-21 NHL season. I want to filter it down to the shots where a certain player was on the ice. That player's name can be in any of the 14 columns that I have listed. if I did something like `dboss = ev[ev['home_on_1'].str.contains('DYLAN.LARKIN')]` I can get all the rows where that name appears in that single column. I can also do something like `dboss = ev[ev['home_on_1'].str.contains('DYLAN.LARKIN') | ev['home_on_2'].str.contains('DYLAN.LARKIN') | ...]` but this is tedious as I have to do it for each column and does not seem very python. I tried the following code,

```
col_list = ['home_on_1', 'home_on_2', 'home_on_3', 'home_on_4',
            'home_on_5', 'home_on_6', 'home_on_7', 'away_on_1', 'away_on_2',
            'away_on_3', 'away_on_4', 'away_on_5', 'away_on_6', 'away_on_7',]
dboss = ev[ev[col_list].str.contains('DYLAN.LARKIN')]
```

This returns `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'` if I remove the .str, I just get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'contains'` Thanks in advance for the help!

*edit to add more information*

Comment: Do you mean 'but that word can be in 1 of 14 *columns* ?

Comment: I did! Thank you, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to filter your dataframe to return only the rows that a player's name appears, in any of the columns. If that, you can utilise `apply()`, which is not efficient, and `any()`, which will search for any condition being `True`, as demonstrated below:

```
player_name = 'DYLAN.LARKIN'
new = df[df[col_list].apply(lambda i: i.str.contains(player_name).any(), axis=1)]
```

- `axis=1` refers to row-wise computations.

Printing back `new`:

```
      home_on_1     home_on_2 home_on_3  ... away_on_5     away_on_6     away_on_7
0  DYLAN.LARKIN          John      John  ...      John  DYLAN.LARKIN          John
1          John          John      John  ...      John          John          John
2          John          John      John  ...      John          John          John
3          John          John      John  ...      John          John          John
4          John  DYLAN.LARKIN      John  ...      John          John  DYLAN.LARKIN
5          John          John      John  ...      John          John          John
6          John          John      John  ...      John          John          John

[7 rows x 14 columns]
```

will return back only the rows that contain at least once the player name you declare.

Sample `DF`:

```
{'home_on_1': {0: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'home_on_2': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'home_on_3': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'home_on_4': {0: 'John',
  1: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'home_on_5': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'DYLAN.LARKIN'},
 'home_on_6': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'home_on_7': {0: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'away_on_1': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'away_on_2': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'away_on_3': {0: 'John',
  1: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'away_on_4': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'DYLAN.LARKIN'},
 'away_on_5': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'away_on_6': {0: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'John',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'},
 'away_on_7': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'John',
  3: 'John',
  4: 'DYLAN.LARKIN',
  5: 'John',
  6: 'John'}}
```

Comment: Yup, this gives me what I need. It is pretty slow. Is that just because python is not great with vectors?

Comment: Glad it works. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) has pretty much everything you need to know about apply, please have a read here

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to approach.

**Approach 1**

```
df['filter_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: any(x == 'string to find'), axis=1)
df[df.filter_col == True]
```

**Approach 2**

```
filter_columns = []
df[df[filter_columns].where(lambda x: x != 'string to find').isnull().sum(axis=1) == 1]
```